# PySerial write doesn't send complete message from script

Tags: python-3.x, shell, scripting, serial-port, pyserial

When I try to send a message through the serial port from the Powershell console, I perfectly receive it on the other side (I am using Termite on the receiver to track the messages). However, when I try to execute exactly the same commands from a script, only the first few bytes of my message are received. I am using Python v3.7.2 and pySerial v3.4

I have already tried waiting some time between opening the serial port and using write for the first time. However, it still doesn't work.

When I execute exactly the same commands from the Powershell console, I manage to receive correctly the whole message on the receiver.

```
   import time
   import serial
   ser = serial.Serial(port = 'COM3', baudrate = 9600, bytesize = 
   serial.EIGHTBITS, parity = serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout = 5)
   msg = 'This is just a message I am trying to send.'
   time.sleep(1)
   ser.write(msg.encode())
```

I am just receiving the message "This" in the receiver. What should actually happen is that on the receiver I should see the complete message I send, and not just the first few characters.

Comment: Try to add `\n` or `\r\n` at the end

Comment: I've seen a similar question yesterday. Somehow related with this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490010/pyserial-cant-write-the-complete-bytes-to-serial-port-hex-data)?